# Not able to fetch Json object from restassured Response(in json)

Tags: java, arrays, json, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am getting response from the server in json format by hitting post request using restAssured using java.

```
Response response = requestSpecification.body(text).post(endpoint);
```

now i want to fetch sub json object named "freebies". How can i perform this operation because when i am writting :

```
JSONObject responseJSONObject = new JSONObject(response);

//jsonObject.getJSONObject("freebies").getString("id");

JSONArray list = jsonObject.getJSONArray("freebies");

String freebies = list.getJSONObject(0).getString("id");

    for (int i = 0; i < freebies.length(); i++) {
        String id = list.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
        System.out.println(id.toString());
        String name = list.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
        System.out.println(name.toString());
        String packName = list.getJSONObject(i).getString("packName");
        System.out.println(packName.toString());
        String quota = list.getJSONObject(i).getString("quota");
        System.out.println(quota.toString());
```

I am getting stackoverFlow err.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the line below to translate restassured response body to JSONObject format:

```
JSONObject responseJSONObject = new JSONObject(response.getBody().asString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ValidatableResponse statusResponse = givenJsonRequest().when()
    .get("/field/entity/test").then();
ArrayList<Map<String,?>> jsonAsArrayList = statusResponse.extract()
    .jsonPath().get("");
Optional<Map<String,?>> filtered = jsonAsArrayList.stream()
    .filter(m -> m.get("fieldName1").equals("Whatever1"))
    .filter(m -> m.get("jsonObject").toString().contains("Whatever2"))
    .findFirst();
Assert.assertTrue(filtered.isPresent(), "Test expected a result after filtering.");
```

Answer (score 0):

In RestAssured 4.4.0 the following works:

`JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.jsonPath().getJsonObject("$"));`